# Angular 4 - Failing Tests Import brosweranimations module

Tags: javascript, angular

My Tests are failing after updating to Angular 4.0.0

```
Error: Found the synthetic property @visibilityChanged. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application. in config/karma-test-shim.js (line 82476)
ZoneAwareError@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:923:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:82476:28
checkNoSyntheticProp@webpack:///~/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js:2945:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:17836:24
```

Tried this approach in karma-test-shim.js to fix but didn't work

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');

require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');

var appContext = require.context('../src', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');
var animation = require('@angular/platform-browser/animations');

testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
  browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
  animation.BrowserAnimationsModule
);
```

Comment: Fixed this: I had to include the BrowserAnimationsModule in the imports spec.ts file not in the karma-test-shim.js

Answer (score -1):

Add `BrowserAnimationsModule` to your project `ngModule` and add `import` also like below:

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
.....
```